# Hide Month not only navigation arrows

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I found an answer on how to hide small calendar navigation arrows to look as a static calender... I have found also some code that hides days on the calender in SharePoint Online calendar (Office 365)

But I need to hide the month as well...tried several things...no success..
[image: month name to hide]

Here what I found to hide the arrows

```
 /* Hides Left Nav Small Calendar, Left/Right Nav(arrow) and Ribbon Tab for changing Scope(Year, Month, Week) */
    div.ms-core-navigation #DatePickerDiv, 
    div.ms-acal-header a[id$="nav_prev_a"], 
    div.ms-acal-header a[id$="nav_next_a"], 

    li[id$="Calendar.Scope"] {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: here what used to hide  navigation arrows and to prevent week/day view

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it in JavaScript, you can just add one line of CSS to hide both the arrows and the month name, like this:

```
<style>
.ms-acal-header{
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

So you don't also need your existing code to hide arrows.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the arrows, but not the month of the calendar in view? @MohamedDerhalli